# Should __ngcc_entry_points__.json be added to source control

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

During the update to Angular 9.1, a file called `__ngcc_entry_points__.json` appeared in all my root folders in the project. Should this file be added to source control, or ignored?

It seems to just contain some hash information, so I assume it can be ignored?

Comment: here this file (__ngcc_entry_points__.json) appeared in that folders : environments
libs ps. Im usin g NX NRWL [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8hd4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8hd4.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created an [issue to get the official response](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36296) and the answer is **NO**. *Feel free to ignore it*.

As its naming suggests it is internal and it should not be written to your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is an issue in the 9.1.0 version and hope the file will not be in the "src" folder with further updates.

Comment: So response is no it should not be added to source control ?

Comment: Yes, I just ignore it

Comment: Fixed in the 9.1.1 version